# How can I compare two columns, determine the value of column 2 from the value in column 1, in VBA, without adding a formula into column 2

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column 1 which, if it has a value, I want to change the value of column 2 to "DEV". I don't want to add the formula into column 2. I am hoping something like this will work:

```
If [@Defect] (column 1) is <> "" Then [@Status] = "DEV"
```

or

```
If ActiveSheet.ListObjects(Table1).ListColumns("Defects").DataBodyRange <> "" Then
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(Table1).ListColumns("Status").DataBodyRange = "DEV"
```

I want to refer to the column name/header to enable reordering the data as needed.
However, I have not seen any examples of this type and I know the syntax is not correct.

Comment: How do you know what column1 and column2 are if you cannot use column numbers?

Comment: It sounds like your varying column order can make your solution rather complex. Can the data be redesigned to always use the same columns in the same order? If not, are the columns identifyable by something unique, such as a heading in row 1?

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code should help you out with determining where your columns are (I do something very similar with some of my reports and it works well for me)

```
Sub gGetCols()
    Dim DefectCol As Long
    Dim StatusCol As Long
    Dim FoundAll As Long
    Dim xlCell As Range
        FoundAll = 0
        Set xlCell = Range("A1")
        Do Until xlCell = ""
            Select Case xlCell
                Case "Defect"
                    DefectCol = xlCell.Column
                    FoundAll = FoundAll + 1
                Case "Status"
                    StatusCol = xlCell.Column
                    FoundAll = FoundAll + 1
            End Select
            If FoundAll = 2 Then Exit Do
            Set xlCell = xlCell.Offset(0, 1)
        Loop
End Sub
```